# How much disk space does Minecraft require?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I would like to store my Minecraft folder on a USB stick. I was wondering how much storage does my USB need in order to hold the Minecraft folder.

For example, will it fit on a 8GB USB, or is it larger?

Answer (score 8):

8GB is more than enough, in fact it is generally less than 1GB. You can check how big the minecraft folder actually is in windows, by doing the following:

- press <kbd>⊞ Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>, which will bring up a prompt. Type `%APPDATA%` and this will open your appdata folder.
- In this folder window that opens there is a `.minecraft` folder. Right click that, then click properties. In the properties window, you will see how large the folder is.

Also, just pointing out that my technic pack folder is around 800MB, and that has a tonne of mods and a lot of saves.

Comment: Yes. If minecraft is freshly downloaded and totally vanilla, it will only at _about less than 250MB_ (With a 1.9 version). But I totally recommended to use **2GB** or more as there will be saves and maybe mods or resource packs.

Answer (score 1):

Regularly it requires up to 1-2 GB of disk space. But if you going to build your own mc server and decide to use entire map of it (3 600 000 000 000 m2) you will need up to 68 petabyte hdd =)

Answer (score 0):

My Minecraft folder is about 8GB including several mods and texture packs, so 8GB would be plenty to store the vanilla game.

Comment: Just as a point of comparison, my largely un-modded Minecraft folder weighs in at a massive... under 120MB footprint if you were to remove my texture packs - under 100MB if you were to additionally delete my saved worlds. So yeah, unless you have a whole bunch of texturepacks and mods, and a massive singleplayer save, 8GB is plenty.

Answer (score 0):

He's right. 8 GB is enough, but some details; virtual machines still work but it might be harder to actually know how much memory you have. Also content packs, mods and texture packs will take up more memory.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you have downloaded into your MC folder (ie. mods or resource packs), how many worlds you have, etc., the size of `.minecraft` varies from person to person. The easiest way to find out how much space you will need is to:

- On a PC: Right click on the `.minecraft` folder and click `Properties`. It may take a second to calculate, but in the middle section it will display how large the folder is.
- On a Mac: Follow [this](http://goo.gl/u2pc4m) tutorial from *iClarified.com*.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

My USB only has around 3 GB of free space before I downloaded it but it holds the launcher and everything else perfectly, so I'd say it's enough. At the most, if you're normal like me, it only takes up 2 GB. However, if you have about a billion packs and mods and worlds it might take up more space.